# Проверить строку на содержательность

Tags: c#, алгоритм, строки

Собственно, нужно проверить, является ли комментарий содержательным, а не чем-то вида "спасибо спасибо спасибо".

Например, функция, подсчитывающая максимальное количество последовательно идущих одинаковых подстрок минимальной длины, которая для

```
- 'ааааа' вернет 5 (подстрока 'а' повторяется 5 раз)
- 'aa aa aa' получается, вернет 2 (подстрока 'аа '. конечно лучше, 
чтоб вернула 3, но не понятно, как реализовать это)
```

а также как можно задать для такой функции минимальную длину анализируемых подстрок
например, если мин. длина равна `3`, то

```
- 'аааааа' вернет 2 (т.е. подстрока 'ааа' повторяется 2 раза)
```

Как можно реализовать такую функцию? Или может есть другие идеи, как отсеять комментарии по содержательности?

Comment: `'аааааа' вернет 2` почему не 6?

Comment: @D-side ну я же написал, что также хотелось бы указывать параметр - минимальную длину проверяемых подстрок. если длина 3, то подстрока 'aaa' повторяется два раз, а более короткие 'a' и 'aa' не рассматриваем. но это не главное. главное все же понять, как реализовать такой алгоритм, можно без дополнительных условий.

Comment: Никак. Ваша задача требует наличия искусственного интеллекта. Подумайте. каким должен быть код, чтобы отличить [это](https://referat.yandex.ru/referats/?t=mathematics+physics) от осмысленного текста.

Comment: @VladD я понимаю, конечно. возможно не совсем правильно расставил акценты в вопросе, но меня интересует именно описанный алгоритм нахождения максимального количества подстрок. пример с комментариями в большей степени приведен именно как пример. то есть я более-менее понимаю, как решить задачу в лоб, но интересуют более элегантные решения

Comment: нужно найти последовательно идущие произвольные подстроки или последовательно идущие слова как частный случай подстрок?

Comment: @ElenaOblomova любые подстроки

Answer (score 8):

На мой взгляд более полезным было бы сначала удалить из комментария слова не несущие информационной нагрузки (понадобится словарик из таких слов), а затем оценить что осталось после удаления и/или соотнести число оставшихся слов с числом удаленных. В любом случае задача эвристическая и фантазировать тут можно до бесконечности.

Answer (score 1):

Текст сообщения можно разбить на [N-граммы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC). Например, биграмма для "на дворе трава, на траве дрова" будет следующей: "на дворе", "дворе трава", "трава на", "на траве", "траве дрова".
Из большого количества текстов с нормальными комментариями надо создать базу данных из разных N-грамм.
После этого новые комментарии также разбиваете на N-граммы и смотрите сколько таких же есть в базе данных.
Например: *"В библиотеке маленький лист разжигают. Огонь… эээ… будет вырабатываться гораздо легче, чем учебник крепкий <...> Вот в магазине 22 она может расщепиться, экономика!"* -- это [шизофазия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F). 
Даже по двум биграммам "учебник крепкий" и "расщепиться экономика" понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попытаться использовать алгоритм классификации с использованием теоремы Байеса, когда подсчитывают вероятность того, является ли данное сообщение содержательным или нет. Собственно, так и работают многие анализаторы спам / не спам. [Ссылка для примера.](http://datareview.info/article/6-prostyih-shagov-dlya-osvoeniya-naivnogo-bayesovskogo-algoritma-s-primerom-koda-na-python/)